# how to convert existing wpf application into kinect based application?

Tags: wpf

I am having a application which is being developed using wpf. The interaction for the application is being done using mouse. Now I need to convert the application which is on mouse click into gesture based application using Kinect. What do I need to do to enable gestures in my current application? My application has button clicks, zooming the image, scroll the content, move the content, rotate zoom and move the 3d model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are touch/gesture-based events that you can hook up to, assuming the Kinect API will trigger them (TouchDown, TouchMove, TouchUp..).

If the Kinect API will not trigger them (or anything in WPF), you might need to write using an external touch/gesture-handling library (ex. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56385/Gesture-Recognition-for-Touch-Devices-Touch-Gestur - granted this is quite old) or write a UI in something Kinect-friendly like perhaps XNA/MonoGame.

Comment: But are there are any events which can help me convert the existing code to Kinect Gesture based.

Comment: If the Kinect triggers the touch events, you can catch those and then raise the regular events based on the arguments of those touch events - this will be a bit complex since you'd have to detect what element was tapped on and send the event to it, depending on what type of touch it was. It's probably easier to just add touch events everywhere and trigger the event handler for the regular events within their handlers (i.e., in the event handler for TouchDown you could call the handler for MouseDown with null or fabricated arguments).